# Akka: Cancel Routing Due To Incorrect Query Parameters

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

So I have a route structure something like this

```
pathPrexix("root"){
  concat {
    path("path") {
      get {
        parameters("someId".as[String], 'fixedValue ! "requiredValue") { params =>

        }
      }
    },
    path(Segment) { extractedValue =>
      .....
    }
  }
}
```

If the user ends a request to the `/root/path` endpoint with the incorrect query parameters (either `someId` missing or `fixedValue` not equal to `value`) then the request will be routed further on to the next route, `root/Segment`. `extractedValue` would in this case be  `path` which would fail and send the user back error handled by the second route.

The preferred behaviour would be to tell the user that they either missed a query parameters or that the query parameter must be one of the given values. Is there any way to make sure that happen?

If I move the second path above the first, it will capture all requests sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `complete` with an appropriate error code if the `get` does not match:

```
path("path") {
  concat(
    get {
      parameters("someId".as[String], 'fixedValue ! "requiredValue") { params =>
      }
    },
    complete(StatusCodes.NotFound)
  )
},
```

You could put additional information in the reply message, but it would be non-standard and therefore would require the client to be aware of it.